# Get reference to Android My Location Overlay Blue dot animation

Tags: android, google-maps, customization, mylocationoverlay

Ok, So I am overwriting MyLocationOverlay in the hopes of removing the blue accuracy ring.

I am overwriting drawMyLocation()

```
 @Override 
        protected void drawMyLocation(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, Location lastFix, GeoPoint myLocation, long when) {
            // translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels
            Point screenPts = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(myLocation, null);



            // create a rotated copy of the marker
            Bitmap arrowBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( mContext.getResources(), android.THISISWHERETHEANIMATIONSHOULDGO);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(mOrientation);
            Bitmap rotatedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                arrowBitmap, 
                0, 0, 
                arrowBitmap.getWidth(), 
                arrowBitmap.getHeight(), 
                matrix, 
                true
            );
            // add the rotated marker to the canvas
            canvas.drawBitmap(
                rotatedBmp, 
                screenPts.x - (rotatedBmp.getWidth()  / 2), 
                screenPts.y - (rotatedBmp.getHeight() / 2), 
                null
            );


        }
```

However, I am finding it impossible to get a reference to the original blue dot animation that is used. How can I go about adding this back in? One single frame of the animation would be acceptable.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just use [location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) to know the user's position ?

Comment: Read my answer again. You say:"However, I am finding it impossible to get a reference to the original blue dot animation that is used. ": answer use your location because the dot is on your position. Do not plot the blue dot and accuracy and then add a dot using location. (read answer before down voting)

Comment: This response answers the question (or at least provides an alternative), however your initial response did not. In fact I was trying to get a reference to the dot animation so i could plot it in the manner you suggested ie. R.drawable.location_dot_animation something like this.